# Speed up Python script or find alternative?

Tags: python

Here's my current script:

```
import argparse
from pybitcointools import *

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('filename')
args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.filename) as textfile:
    for line in textfile:
       priv = sha256(line.rstrip())
       wif_u = encode_privkey(priv, 'wif')
       wif_c = encode_privkey(priv, 'wif_compressed')
       addr_u = pubtoaddr(privtopub(priv))
       addr_c = pubtoaddr(compress(privtopub(priv)))
       print("%s,%s" % (addr_u, wif_u))
       print("%s,%s" % (addr_c, wif_c))
```

I run this script to convert 1000 lines into 2000 bitcoin brain wallets (1000 x 2 to include both compressed and uncompressed).  It takes 12.5 seconds to run.

If I remove these lines, it goes down from 12.5 seconds to 0.2 seconds:

```
addr_u = pubtoaddr(privtopub(priv))
addr_c = pubtoaddr(compress(privtopub(priv)))
```

But of course, I need the addresses, not just the private keys in WIF format.

So here's the 3 things I'm trying to figure out:

1. Why does address generation take so much longer than private key generation?
2. Is there a way to speed up the existing Python script to run in less than a second?
3. If not, does anyone know of a simple alternative that could do this faster?

I don't mind using Python, Perl, C, whatever does the job and is the fastest.

Comment: Without going too deeply into your code. Python is an interpreted programming language. Any operation that requires fast access to CPU/GPU/memory can only benefit from being written in C or C#. Why don't you try and benchmark.

Comment: Use any language that supports multi core processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `privtopub(priv)` twice. This would save a call to `fast_multiply` which is likely the slowest function in this entire program.

I would suggest first doing:

```
pub = privtopub(priv)
addr_u = pubtoaddr(pub)
addr_c = pubtoaddr(compress(pub))
```

Then I would suggest using a `multiprocessing.Pool`:

```
import argparse
from pybitcointools import *

def convert(line):
    priv = sha256(line.rstrip())
    wif_u = encode_privkey(priv, 'wif')
    wif_c = encode_privkey(priv, 'wif_compressed')
    pub = privtopub(priv)
    addr_u = pubtoaddr(pub)
    addr_c = pubtoaddr(compress(pub))
    return (addr_u, wif_u, addr_c, addr_u)

if __name__=="__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('filename')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    with open(args.filename) as textfile:
        for addr_u, wif_u, addr_c, addr_u in pool.imap(convert, textfile):
            print("%s,%s" % (addr_u, wif_u))
            print("%s,%s" % (addr_c, wif_c))
```